# Bidirectional inverted binding between two BooleanProperties

Tags: java, javafx

First, naive attempt:

```java
booleanProperty1.bindBidirectional(booleanProperty2.not()); // type mismatch
```

This doesn't work. I either have to change it to unidirectional bind (so it will accept `BooleanBinding` as an argument) or remove `.not()`.

What would be the best way to actually achieve my goal here?

Comment: Why have them both at all? There is no advantage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most easiest way is to include listeners to both the properties and inverse the value to set on other property.

```
booleanProperty1.addListener((obs,old,val)->booleanProperty2.set(!val));
booleanProperty2.addListener((obs,old,val)->booleanProperty1.set(!val));
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a listener to booleanProperty2.

Upon its value changing (triggering the listener), set booleanProperty to the opposite of booleanProperty2.